# Weird behavior with Dart List

Tags: list, flutter, sorting, dart, bubble-sort

```
List<List<int>> arr = [];

List<int> bubbleSort(List<int> list) {
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < list.length - 1; j++) {
      if (list[j] > list[j + 1]) {
        int num = list[j];
        list[j] = list[j + 1];
        list[j + 1] = num;
        arr.add(list);
      }
    }
  }
  return list;
}

void main(){
  bubbleSort([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]);
  print(arr);
}
```

I implemented Bubble sort in dart and after every swap i'm adding the list to the arr but i'm getting an unexpected output:

> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

Somehow all the contents of *arr* are the same.
Please explain how to resolve this and why this is happening.

Comment: You are always adding and modifying the same list instance.

Comment: You are adding the same instance of a mutable list to `arr`. Instead of doing `arr.add(list);`, you could add a copy of the list by doing `arr.add(list.toList());` or `arr.add([...list]);`

Comment: Remove `arr` and just return the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void swap(List<int> arr, int xp, int yp) {
  var temp = arr[xp];
  arr[xp] = arr[yp];
  arr[yp] = temp;
}

List<int> applyBubbleSort(List<int> arr) {
  var n = arr.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) {
      if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) swap(arr, j, j+1);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  var result = applyBubbleSort(
    // [5, 3, 1, 9, 8, 2, 4, 7]
    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  );
  print(result);
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```